# How to force detach EBS from EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I can't restart my EC2 instance, and there are important data in both the EC2 instance and external EBS volume.

Now I want to mount the EBS in my new temporarily created EC2 instance, and fix that old EC2 instance later. I  detached the EBS volume in the AWS Console, but the EBS state is still remains in `i-6da1cf05:/dev/sdf (detaching)' state and can't be attached to the new EC2 instance.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add --force option to ec2-detach-volume utility:

```
sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools
ec2-detach-volume [LOGIN-OPTIONS] --force VOL-ID
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a potential for data loss when you do this. Read more about --force here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2010-08-31/CommandLineReference/index.html?ApiReference-cmd-DetachVolume.html

Comment: Console allows this now too.